# Can you denote a specified calculation as a subscript to a variable?

Tags: geometry

I will use an arbitrary scenario for simplicity.

Say I have a rectangle, $B$, with:

$w = 3$ centimeters

$l = 6$ centimeters

Then I ask what the area of the rectangle is. We then say that "$A = 18$cm$^2$ of rectangle $B$".

Can you utilize a subscript to denote quickly what calculation you are referring to? Say I make the area of the box = $B_{\text{area}}$ where subscript "area" denotes that we are taking the area of the rectangle, $B$.

Then, if I add a new rectangle, $F$, it would be universally known if I ask for $F_{\text{area}}$ I would be referring to the calculation of the area of rectangle, F.

We could say then either:

"Area of $F$ =" or we could say "$F_{\text{area}} =$".

Comment: I think that a more direct approach would be write something like "let area(D) denotes de area of the polygon D". In that way, you can further use area(B), area(F),  etc, without need any additional explanation.

Comment: @RenatoFernandes that sounds good. In this case, what is "area", is it a function or a callout of sorts?

Comment: Yes. You interpret it as a function, but don't worry too much about it. It is more simple to think it as a simple notation. It is quite common in mathematics to define things that way. Also, there is nothing "wrong" with your solution, but it is not very common to define measures using 
 a notation in subscripts.

Comment: Thanks for the help @RenatoFernandes